# check parameters of a function with Babel

Tags: javascript, plugins, babeljs, babel-plugin, babel-babylon

I want to check parameters of a function to be in a range with babel. I mean I want to change the following code:

```
function(arg1, arg2)
{
     body of function
}
```

to this code:

```
function checkRange(argument)
{
       some checking
}
function(arg1, arg2)
{
     checkRange(arg1);
     checkRange(arg2);
     body of function
}
```

how can I do this with Babel? I read this tutorial: https://lihautan.com/step-by-step-guide-for-writing-a-babel-transformation/ and I also read a number of examples in https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages and more and more. but I'm very beginner in Babel

Comment: welcome! you read the tutorial and the examples. what did you learn from it? what did not work, precisely?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use inner function like this :

```
function(arg1, arg2)
{
 function checkRange(argument)
 {
   some checking
 }

 checkRange(arg1);
 checkRange(arg2);
 body of function
}
```

Comment: yes. I want to do this with Babel. because I have a lot of files with a lot of functions in it. I can't do this manually.

Comment: how can i do this with babel?

Comment: i mean @Babel/core